# Where is the class (including struct and dynamic variables) stored?

Tags: c++, struct

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class message
{
    private:
        HeaderType header;
        // Message text
        byte * text;    

    public:
        message(int ID,struct in_addr senderIP);
        ~message();
        HeaderType getHeader();
        byte * getText();
};
```

where HeaderType is a struct as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    int mID;
    struct in_addr mIP;
}HeaderType;
```

Where is the class (including struct and dynamic variables) stored (Stack, heap ...)?

P.S. I declare a `message m` as a static variable.

Comment: Classes and structures are the same and stored identically. They are located in stack, if you just declare them in your code: `Class obj; Struct n(10);`. They're located in heap, if you create them in heap: `Class* obj = new Class(); Struct* n = new Struct(10);`

Comment: `class`es and `struct`s aren't stored on the stack or the heap, *objects or instances*  of classes and structs are allocated on the stack or the heap depending on how did you allocate them.

Comment: Please all, I know I know that in general they are allocated depending on its case (dynamic or static). My question is regarding the dynamic variables inside the static class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> classes are stored in stack, while structs are allocated in free store

That is not correct at all. They are the same thing, except `struct` members are `public` by default, and `class` members are `private` by default.

Where the memory is allocated depends solely on you you instantiate the object.

```
Foo a;             // instantiated on the stack
Foo b* = new Foo;  // on the heap
```

It doesn't matter if `Foo` above is a `struct` or `class`, they behave the same way.

In your example, the member `byte* text;` will be allocated along with your class. More explicitly, if you instantiate a `message` on the stack, `text` will be allocated on the stack; if you instantiate a `message` on the heap, `text` will be allocated on the heap.

That being said, the location of the object being pointed to does not have to be the same place as the pointer. For example

```
int* x;               // This is a pointer declared on the stack

int a = 5;            // This is an int declared on the stack
int* b = new int(5);  // This is an int declared on the heap

x = &a;       // pointing to a stack object
x = b;        // pointing to a heap object
x = nullptr;  // pointing to nothing!
```

So you can see that the memory for the actual pointer, and the memory of the object being pointed at are unrelated. In fact, in that very last line, the pointer was instantiated, but was pointing at `nullptr`.

Comment: what about my question, where this class includes dynamic variables? What happens to those variables?

Comment: @Moi a class doesn't contain "dynamic variables". It contains a member `text`. That member is stored where the class is stored (if the object was allocated in automatic or dynamic memory). What it points to also depends on how it's created - you can have a pointer to a variable in automaitc storage (stack) just fine (i.e. `int a; int* x = &a` - here, both `a` and `x` are on the stack)

Comment: *"Foo a; // instantiated on the stack"* - true if inside a function, but if that appears at global or namespace scope the variable will be in yet another area of either initialised or uninitialised data (depending on a combination of the bitwise representation of the constructed object, optimiser, linker, loader).

Comment: @TonyD, even the member 'text' for both cases?

Comment: @Moi: several people have already explained this, but I'll have a crack too.  The pointer value itself is effectively a number which can be used to store a 0-based number of the byte into virtual memory where some other useful data's stored (your actual textual data).  So the pointer might be 1234 and at address 1234 there'd be "hello\n".  The mere existence of a pointer says nothing at all about whether it points at anything, let alone what allocation method was used to get the memory to which it points.  So, the text can also be stack, heap, uninitialised or initialised data segment....

Answer (score 1):

To your corrected question:

Static instance of `message` will be located at the data segment. The memory for each non-pointer member (including members of `HeaderType`) is reserving at compile-time. At the start of the program will be called the constructors of `message` and `HeaderType`, that will initialize this memory.

If construct of `message` will allocate the memory for `byte* text`, this memory will be in a heap.

Comment: yes, the constructor includes text = (byte *)malloc (10); memset (text, '.', 10); So, you mean that message is allocated in stack while text is allocated in heap. Right?

Comment: Almost. Static data stores not in stack, it stores in the data segment before the heap. Suppose you have the string: `static char s[] = "Some string\n";`. If you look inside your **.exe**, somewhere you'll find this string. It's stores together the code, and will be loaded in memory together the code. This memory can't be "released" or "freed", although you can change it. This memory is not a stack or heap, but actually it usually located just before a heap.